# KahaDBStore vs KahaDBPersistenceAdapter

Tags: activemq-classic

I m using ActiveMQ 5.9.1 for implementing queue. I had been using KahaDBPersistenceAdapter for persistence.
Recently I found that KahaDBStore is also a persitence adapter.
Anyone please advise which persistence adapter is better for activemq 5.9.1 . What are the differences between the two implementations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KahaDBPersistenceAdapter is a class which is built to perform opeartions  on KahaDB database.

KahaDb is a lightweight,Fast and embedded database in ActiveMQ which is presaent by default with activemq.

So there is no difference between these two.
KahaDBPersistenceAdapter internally works with KahaDB

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Vihar, thanks for the answer.I have one more question . I havent set any  maxfilesixe for journal. The default values seems to be 32 mb. Whenevr I test in my local machine, the .log file seems to be 32 mb (in teh beginning itself) and doesnt change. But when i deploy in a dedicated linux machine, the .log file size becoming 33030144(kb) . Any idea why it behaves like this. I have set the store usage to 3 gb

Comment: Ok, I realize the file size in linux is in bytes